# How demanding are sql queries vs opening a connection

Tags: sql, performance, connection

So, I know opening a connection to a server is a time consuming operation and you want to limit that as much as possible. I was curious how demanding an actual sql query is on the server?

So, you have a list of 100 employee id's and you want to get their names. You have two options.

1. Pull the entire list of employees down (we'll assume for arguments sake this list is no more than 1k) and compare them against the results
2. Pull each name given the id resulting in 100 seperate sql queries.

Is option 2 way worse than option 1?

Also, I know that this may depend. If the total size of the table is in the millions, then obviously option 2 is desirable with small amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

For 10 rows: a single query.
For large data: stored procedure, table valued parameter (IDs), a rowset as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit subjective and has so many variables left undefined.  Which database server? Which version? What hardware? How is table or tables stored on disk? What else is accessing the server?  How is the table indexed?....I could go on and on.

If you are trying to make an architecture decision, I think you need to define the functional requirement first to get a decent answer.

Comment: The idea was to be an "in general" discussion. On average, which option would you choose. But to satisfy the origin of my question. Consider a web site where the server and the sql server are not the same machine. Browser->javascript->ajaxCall->server->sql server

Godaddy's servers and a mysql server

Comment: I would say 100 queries is better if you are talking about doing the data manipulation in javascript, otherwise you are copying down the entire table to the client's browsers memory space...yikes!  Ideally you should be able to write a query that returns everything you need in one database call.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of connection is very high to will have a performance issue. Is beter to have the connection opens low.

More information on connection pools [here](http://www.pythian.com/blog/sql-server-understanding-and-controlling-connection/)